# Stop iteration in a 2d matrix with break

Tags: c#, matrix, iteration, break

I was wondering how can I stop the iteration through the rows and columns of a 2d matrix if a value is found.

```
int[,] matrix = new int[8, 10];

Random rnd = new Random();

bool value = false;

for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
{
  for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
  {
    int number = rnd.Next(1, matrix.Length + 1);
    matrix[row, col] = number;
    Console.Write("{0,3}", number);

    if (number == 8)
    {
       value = true;
       break;           
    }                
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a boolean flag or move the double loop to a separate method and use `return`

Comment: Thank you, that flag trick works. I'll also try the version with method and return.